# MapStruct: How to use mapper to map View Objects with Composite Key JPA?

Tags: jpa, mapstruct

I have target entity like following:

```
public class ApplicationUsage {
    @Id
    private ApplicationUsagePK appUsage;    //Guid  No documentation available.
    private String name;
    .
    .
    public ApplicationUsage(String id, Integer compId) {
       this.appUsage = new ApplicationUsagePK(id, compId); //This is present in ApplicationUsagePK initiated here which acts are composite key
    }
```

The Source Object is like below:

```
public class ApplicationUsage {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
```

I need to Map ID of source object to *applicationUsage(String id* and CompID is coming from some other variable and it needs to map with *applicationUsage(.., Integer compId)*

What changes are required in above class or mapper to achieve the same?

Following is current mapper:

```
@Mapper
public interface ApplicationUsageMapper {
    ApplicationUsageMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper( ApplicationUsageMapper.class );

    ApplicationUsage entityToDao(com.inte.meow.vo.computer.ApplicationUsage source);
}
```

Bad way:

I have used bad way to fix this which you can understand looking into following:

```
ApplicationUsage aUsage = ApplicationUsageMapper.MAPPER.entityToDao(agreement.getBody());
aUsage.initiateApplicationUsage(agreement.getBody().getId(), compId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using `@Context` annotation

```
@Mapper
public interface ApplicationUsageMapper {
    ApplicationUsageMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper( ApplicationUsageMapper.class );

    @Mapping(target = "appUsage", source = "source", qualifiedByName = "getAppUsage")
    ApplicationUsage entityToDao(com.inte.meow.vo.computer.ApplicationUsage source, @Context Integer compId);

    @Named("getAppUsage")
    default ApplicationUsagePK toAppUsage(com.inte.meow.vo.computer.ApplicationUsage source, @Context Integer compId) {
        return new ApplicationUsagePK (source.getId(), compId));
    }
}
```